# posts2posts query using connected_items array issue

Tags: wp-query, plugin-posts-to-posts

**My setup is as follows**

I hava a custom post type named 'events' and a custom post type named 'genres' which I link with scribu's Posts2Posts plugin. Each event can have multiple genres linked to it.

**What I would like to do**

*On an event page*, I'd like to show other, related, events based on the genres the current event has.

What I think I should do

1. Run a query which gets all the genres IDs of the current event
2. Pass these IDs in a second query which finds all the events which have one or more of these genres linked to it

I have a p2p query which I'd like to output all events which have one AND / OR more of the given genres in connected_items. I pass them as an array, just like in the documentation.

To illustrate my outcome, lets say that

- event1 has linked genres with post ids 1240, 1241, 1242 and 1250
- event2 has linked genres with post ids 1240, 1241 and 1260
- event3 has linked genres with post ids 1241 and 1242

In the first query I get all the genre IDs, this works.

The second query which gets all the events with the given genres (I pass them as an array):

```
$args = array(
        'connected_type' => 'genres_to_events',
        'connected_items' => array(1240,1241,1242),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

The thing is that the output checks for each connection in the array, and therefor the output of the query is:

- event1
- event1
- event1
- event2
- event2
- event3
- event3

But I'd like to output each event once based on if it has one or more of the genres connected to it. I don't think this is explained in the documentation, any ideas?

Comment: When you say p2p I keep thinking of scribu's plugin [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) - Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yes that's right, sorry for not mentioning. I'll update my question.

Comment: When you get `connected_items` why use an array instead of the current `$post->ID`, as one would do while in a loop? Seems are you are combining the looping method of p2p and the single method, into one strange method. https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/each_connected

Comment: That would get the genres for each event. What I like to do is: when on an event page, get the genres for that event (this is working) and then (still on this event page) show other events which also have one or more of these genres attached to it. The last part isn't working. I've updated my question to illustrate the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I think I understand. I think what you should do with your first loop, is get the connected genres as you say. Then you wish to get all events that are related to those, so you should gather only the IDs (collect them in one array) in a loop, and then use `array_unique()` to remove all the duplicates. Use this clean array in a loop to get just those posts then. Make sense?

So, something like this might work:

```
$args = array(
        'connected_type' => 'genres_to_events',
        'connected_items' => array(1240,1241,1242),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);

$connected_out = array();

while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
    $connected_out[] = $post->ID;
endwhile;

$connected_out = array_unique($connected_out);
wp_reset_query();

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $connected_out;
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
// go!
```

Comment: Thanks! I've figured that I can use `$related = p2p_type('genres_to_events')->get_related($query, array(), 'events');`. Then use a `while` loop just like a normal with a normal `wp_query` to get the related posts. I can then use your method to filter out the duplicates (I'll try that step first). Then I've got one question left; how can I use more arguments in this query (like meta_compare etc)? We're almost there! I'll try your method for removing duplicates with the `$related` part first and update my question if it works.

Comment: My previous comment was a bit stupid since I can just add that arguments to the last `$args` mentioned in your solution. I've combined your solution with the `get_related` method above and your solution works perfectly! (and I've now also learned about `array_unique` :-))

Comment: Cool. Glad that works for you!

Comment: Just encountered another problem. If I use the `$related` method as described above, it limits the results to 10 posts. This wouldn't work in my situation, since I have hundreds of events. So I'm back to using a query with `connected_type` etc to get an array of the posts (but the `array_unique` method is still useful of course). Will update when it works...

Comment: `'posts_per_page' => -1` -- a limit of 10 might need overridden somewhere. Look into that.

Comment: I've been looking to pass the `posts_per_page` argument to get_related, but no luck yet. Posted a question on the p2p wp support page, see [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pass-arguments-to-get_related). Keep you posted.

Comment: Found it, see my 'answer' below.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer since it partially is and because I need some more characters than available in the comments. Hope that's OK :-).

So I've found the `posts_per_page` issue after reading [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-posts-2-posts-pass-query-parameters-to-get_related?replies=3).

It's possible to pass arguments to the `get_related` function, although it seems like you'd have to modify the p2p core. What I did was add my own `get_related` function, named `my_get_related`.

Code is as follows:

```
public function my_get_related( $item, $extra_qv = array(), $output = 'raw' ) {
        $extra_qv['fields'] = 'ids';

        $connected = $this->get_connected( $item, $extra_qv, 'abstract' );

        $additional_qv = array( 'p2p:exclude' => _p2p_normalize( $item ), 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

        return $this->flip_direction()->get_connected( $connected->items, $additional_qv, $output );
    }
```

I've added this in wp-content/plugins/posts-to-posts/core/directed-connection-type.php (the original `get_related` function is on line 94).

You can see the `'posts_per_page'` argument added, more can be easily added by separating them by commas.

Now I still have one question: how do I declare this function outside of the p2p core file? I don't want to add it there since it could backfire when updating the plugin. I'd like to add it to my functions.php (I use the Roots theme so it will be in some other file than functions.php but it's the same as putting it there since the file I'll put it in is an include of functions.php).

I've tried `public function my_get_related...` and `add_action('p2p_init', 'my_get_related')` but that doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to add this function outside of the core?

I think that after that, the problem is finally solved :-)

Comment: `$connected = new WP_Query( array(
  'connected_type' => 'posts_to_pages',
  'connected_items' => get_queried_object(),
  'nopaging' => true,
) );` -- it's all about the nopaging. https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage

Comment: True, but then I'd still not use the function `get_related`... The query you're suggesting would get me the genres, then I'd have to put them in a second query to get the related festivals. `get_related` does that in one go, so I'm hoping I can define the function outside of the plugin's core file.